# Dapper provide default name for dynamic result sets with QueryMultiple

Tags: c#, dapper

TLDR; Is there a way (using a type map or some other solution) to give `dynamic` result sets a default name, such as "(No Column Name)" in Dapper when no column name is supplied?

I am writing a query editor that allows users to write and run user-supplied queries against MS SQL Server databases. I've been using Dapper for all our querying and it has been working beautifully for 99% of what we need. I've hit a snag though and I'm hoping someone has a solution.

The query editor is similar to SSMS. I don't know ahead of time what the script will look like, what the shape or type the result set(s) will be, or even how many result sets will be returned. For this reason, I've been batching the scripts and using Dapper's `QueryMultiple` to read `dynamic` results from the `GridReader`. The results are then sent to a third party UI data grid (WPF). The data grid knows how to consume dynamic data and the only thing it requires to display a given row is at least one key value pair with a non-null, but not necessarily unique key and a nullable value. So far, so good.

The simplified version of the Dapper call looks something like this:

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>> QueryMultipleAsync<T>(string sql, 
                                                                             object parameters, 
                                                                             string connectionString,
                                                                             CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text, 
                                                                             CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = null)
        {
            using (IDbConnection con = _dbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(connectionString))
            {

                con.Open();
                var transaction = con.BeginTransaction();

                var sqlBatches = sql
                    .ToUpperInvariant()
                    .Split(new[] { " GO ", "\r\nGO ", "\n\nGO ", "\nGO\n", "\tGO ", "\rGO "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                var batches = new List<CommandDefinition>();

                foreach(var batch in sqlBatches)
                {
                    batches.Add(new CommandDefinition(batch, parameters, transaction, null, commandType, CommandFlags.Buffered, cancellationTokenSource.Token));
                }

                var resultSet = new List<List<T>>();

                foreach (var commandDefinition in batches)
                {
                    using (GridReader reader = await con.QueryMultipleAsync(commandDefinition))
                    {
                        while (!reader.IsConsumed)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var result = (await reader.ReadAsync<T>()).AsList();
                                if (result.FirstOrDefault() is IDynamicMetaObjectProvider)
                                {
                                    (result as List<dynamic>).ConvertNullKeysToNoColumnName();
                                }
                                resultSet.Add(result);
                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                if(e.Message.Equals("No columns were selected"))
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    throw;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                try
                {
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    if (transaction != null)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                    }
                }

                return resultSet;
            }
        }

public static IEnumerable<dynamic> ConvertNullKeysToNoColumnName<dynamic>(this IEnumerable<dynamic> rows)
        {
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                if (row is IDictionary<string, object> rowDictionary)
                {
                    if (rowDictionary == null) continue;

                    rowDictionary.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Key)).ToList().ForEach(x =>
                    {
                        var val = rowDictionary[x.Key];

                        if (x.Value == val)
                        {
                            rowDictionary.Remove(x);
                            rowDictionary.Add("(No Column Name)", val);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Trace.WriteLine("Something went wrong");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            return rows;
        }
```

This works with most queries (and for queries with only one unnamed result column), but the problem manifests when the user writes a query with more than one unnamed column like this:

`select COUNT(*), MAX(create_date) from sys.databases`.

In this case, Dapper returns a DapperRow that looks something like this:

`{DapperRow,  = '9',  = '2/14/2020 9:51:54 AM'}`

So the result set is exactly what the user asks for (i.e., values with no names or aliases) but I need to supply (non-unique) keys for all data in the grid...

My first thought was to simply change the null keys in the `DapperRow` object to a default value (like '(No Column Name)'), as it appears to be optimized for storage so table keys are only stored once in the object (which is nice and would provide a nice performance bonus for queries with huge result sets). The `DapperRow` type is private though. After searching around, I found that I could cast the `DapperRow` to an `IDictionary<string, object>` to access keys and values for the object, and even set and remove values. That's where the `ConvertNullKeysToNoColumnName` extension method comes from. And it works... But only once.

Why? Well, it appears that when you have multiple null or empty keys in a `DapperRow` that gets cast to an `IDictionary<string,object>` and you call the `Remove(x)` function (where x is the entire item OR just the key for any single item with a null or empty key), all subsequent attempts to resolve other values with a null or empty key via the indexer `item[key]` fail to retrieve a value--even if the additional key value pairs still exist in the object.

In other words, I can't remove or replace subsequent empty keys after the first one is removed.

Am I missing something obvious? Do I just need to alter the `DapperRow` via reflection and hope it doesn't have any weird side affects or that the underlying data structure doesn't change later? Or do I take the performance/memory hit and just copy/map the entire potentially large result set into a new sequence to give empty keys a default value at runtime?

Comment: I tried to debug this locally, but ran into trouble in several places. First, your code says that the 'cancellationTokenSource' is optional, but crashes if it's not supplied. Next, the column names are not empty strings on all databases - what database are you using?

I suspect that this has something to do with the fact that both columns will have the same key, so when you try to get the second one out of the dict with `rowDictionary[x.Key];`, you actually get the first one.

Comment: Have you considered using a datatable instead of a list of dynamic objects? I suspect that would work just fine with the grid view component. It handles duplicate column names by itself, and you can change the column names after the reader step if you want.

Comment: @gnud --Good call on the CancellationTokenSource. All the consumers have one at the moment, so I overlooked it. I will definitely revisit it.

Comment: @gnud -- As for the datatable, the thought did cross my mind but it felt wrong considering moving away from datatables was one of the best parts about Dapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is because the dynamic DapperRow object is actually not a 'normal' dictionary. It can have several entries with the same key. You can see this if you inspect the object in the debugger.

When you reference `rowDictionary[x.Key]`, I suspect you will always get the first unnamed column.

If you call `rowDictionary.Remove(""); rowDictionary.Remove("");`, you actually only remove the first entry - the second is still present, even though `rowDictionary.ContainsKey("")` returns false.

You *can* `Clear()` and rebuild the entire dictionary.
At that point, you're really not gaining much by using a dynamic object.

```
if (row is IDictionary<string, object>)
{
    var rowDictionary = row as IDictionary<string, object>;
    if (rowDictionary.ContainsKey(""))
    {
        var kvs = rowDictionary.ToList();
        rowDictionary.Clear();

        for (var i = 0; i < kvs.Count; ++i)
        {
            var kv = kvs[i];

            var key = kv.Key == ""? $"(No Column <{i + 1}>)" : kv.Key;
            rowDictionary.Add(key, kv.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Since you're working with unknown result structure, and just want to pass it to a grid view, I would consider using a DataTable instead.

You can still keep Dapper for parameter handling:

```
foreach (var commandDefinition in batches)
{
    using(var reader = await con.ExecuteReaderAsync(commandDefinition)) {
        while(!reader.IsClosed) {
            var table = new DataTable();
            table.Load(reader);
            resultSet.Add(table);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate all your feedback. Thank you for your time. I am running against `master` in a SQL Server 2017 instance with the query `select COUNT(*), MAX(create_date) from sys.databases`. Unfortunately, however, your example has the same problem on my machine: those while loops only run once and all subsequent calls to `IDictionary.ContainsKey` do not find the additional null or empty key. I'm looking at the [source](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper/SqlMapper.DapperRow.cs) and it seems to be pretty standard here.

Comment: It actually appears that the [DapperTable](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/61e965eed900355e0dbd27771d6469248d798293/Dapper/SqlMapper.DapperTable.cs#L20) may hold the clue. That `fieldNameLookup` variable is a standard `Dictionary<>` object, which explains the behavior. They even acknowledge the potential for duplicates and make a decision on who the 'winner' should be. I guess I'll have to keep digging.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. After fighting uphill against this for way too long, I wound up going with the DataTable route.